# Issue formatting data in JavaScript for a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am not a JavaScript expert and I am trying to put a simple pie chart together using the data from a csv file. The sample code for the pie chart with its input data looks like below and it works perfectly.

```
var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
        header: {
            title: {
                text: "A Very Simple Pie",
                fontSize: 30
            }
        },
        data: {
            content: [
                { label: "JavaScript", value: 264131 },
                { label: "Ruby", value: 218812 },
                { label: "Java", value: 157618}
            ]
        }
    });
```

but when I try to use the data from the csv file. It says no data is provided. I obviously try to pass the dynamic data to the `data.content` but it seems like I am not doing it correctly. Below is my code:

```
var input_data = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {

    input_data.push({
        label: data["First"],
        value: +data["Age"]
    });
});

console.log(input_data); // This shows [{label: "james", value:30},{"John",value:22}]
var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
    header: {
        title: {
            text: "Simple Pie",
            fontSize: 30
        }
    },
    data: {
        content: input_data
    }
});
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `d3.csv` operates asynchronously, and `d3pie` is trying to create your chart before `input_data` has been populated. Quick and easy fix is to move the code that creates the pie chart inside the `d3.csv` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, your problem is because `d3.csv` acts asynchronously, and `input_data` isn't populated when `d3pie` tries to create your chart.

There is something highly suspicious going on with `input_data` in the other examples -- it should be called for every item in `data`, but seems only to be called once. Rather than using `input_data` to collate intermediate results, it's much easier to use [javascript's `map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform your csv data into the format you want:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {
    var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
        header: {
         title: {
             text: "Simple Pie",
             fontSize: 30
            }
        },
        data: {
            content: data.map( function(d){
                return { label: d['First'], value: +d['Age'] }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

`map` iterates over an array and produces an array as output, so it's much cleaner and easier than creating extra arrays on to which you push data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to put your `d3pie` code inside your callback function because you want to call it after the data returns (see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346#csv.js)):

```
var input_data = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {
    input_data.push({
        label: data["First"],
        value: +data["Age"]
    });
    console.log(input_data); // This shows [{label: "james", value:30},{"John",value:22}]
    var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
        header: {
            title: {
                text: "Simple Pie",
                fontSize: 30
            }
        },
        data: {
            content: input_data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but it renders the chart twice. once with one slice and once with two slices.

Comment: @jax I hope that csv callback is the only place you're calling `new d3pie(...)`.

Comment: yes it is. it seems like everything within the `d3.csv` is called as many as number of rows you have. Also, I noticed that the `console.log()` is shown twice as well once with one element and once with two elements. (my data has only two rows for testing purposes )

Comment: @jax It's hard to tell why that could be happening. Maybe you're calling `d3.csv(...)` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

```
const promise = d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {
    input_data.push({
        'label': data["First"],
        'value': +data["Age"]
    });
});

promise.then(function(){
    var pie = new d3pie("pieChart", {
        header: {
            title: {
                text: "Simple Pie",
                fontSize: 30
            }
        },
        data: {
            content: input_data
        }
    });
});
```